# Save Octet-stream data as PDF file in javascript

Tags: node.js, express, pdf, node-streams

**Scenario 1:**

Need to convert the below mentioned stream data into file in nodejs

Stream data sample: https://gist.github.com/sriramgroot/33e6e4934081f3d1b9d70c88873f2ad9

---

**Scenario 2:**

Need to convert the below mentioned stream data into file in browser using reactjs framework

Stream data sample: https://gist.github.com/sriramgroot/33e6e4934081f3d1b9d70c88873f2ad9

---

**Response Header**

[image]

**Note:** Final output should be a PDF file and it should be blank document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution for saving the file, and it if possible in **Scenario 1**.

1. In Octet-stream you will be receiving the response as "Encoded Binary Data"
2. Your need to convert the response data into "Decoded Base64 String"
3. Finally save it as PDF

Also we can use NPM package - [Base64toPDF](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64topdf) for making the listed process as automated.

Comment: Could you post your code example here, please? I installed the Base64toPDF package but still can't get it to work—many thanks.